# Sync of bitcoin main-net does not finished yet. Are there any ways to speed up it?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I'm downloading bitcoin main-net node to AWS instance. However it doesn't finished yet even though it has already passed four days.
My node's latest block is 321,744, and the latest block of Bitcoin main-net is 385,707.
Could you tell me how to hasten the speed of downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably using 100% CPU? Maybe you can add some CPU temporarily? Which version are you running? 0.12 is currently in beta and is about 5x faster with signature checking, which is the biggest CPU user. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes.md

Comment: Does it mean I need to add some CPU temporarily to AWS EC2? Now I am using t2.micro.